# Width of Confidence Intervals for Variance Estimates in Contrast to Point Estimates

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, econometrics, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian

We are conducting a variance decomposition using a hierarchical linear random effects Bayesian model to investigate the variance in a DV that is affected by three nested layers. We estimate credible (confidence) intervals (from the posterior distribution) for the variance explained by each of the layers. We observe that they are larger than “usual”, when comparing them to the credible intervals of the point estimates. We are wondering if this is to be expected given that the variance is a quadratic term.

Comment: See https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2288-14-121 for a simulation study. The answer appears to be that yes, it is expected, especially if using non-informative priors. Anecdotally, I observed this in a couple of relatively simple models I ran for a continuous outcome model with a two-level nested hierarchy..

Comment: Thank you so much. Highly appreciated